# Location of the maximum of the function $x \mapsto \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, approximation, maxima-minima

> Determine location of the maximum of the function $$x \mapsto \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}$$ for $x>0$. Evaluate it with $2$-digit precision. Hint: $3 e^{-3} \approx 0.15$

---

I calculated

$$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d} x} \left( \frac{x^3}{e^x-1} \right) = \frac{3x^2(e^x-1)-x^3e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}$$

So the root can be calculated from equation $e^x(3-x)=3$. However, I don't know how to derive $x$ from this equation and I don't know how to use information from the hint

$$\frac{3}{e^3} \approx 0.15$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: But $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty} \dfrac{x^3}{\mathrm{e}^x-1}=+\infty$.

Comment: Have you been asked to solve the problem for $x\geq 0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) defines $W(z)$ to be the value $w$ that satisfies $we^w=z$.

Your equation can be written as $(x-3)e^{x-3} = -3/e^3$ so $x=W(-3/e^3) + 3$. Do you have some way of numerically approximating the Lambert W function?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I can calculate Lambert W function as the Taylor series

Comment: @MikhailObuchalov, just use Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 0):

Rearranging you have $x = 3(1 - e^{-x})$. In this case a simple fixed point iteration will do the job: $x' \leftarrow 3(1 - e^{-x})$ with an initial guess of $x = 1$ gets you 2.8214... in less than a dozen iterations.[Added] But see the comment of @g.kov.